# Variable not updating from a property

Tags: vuejs3

I am new to Vue and trying to populate a variable in a component and sending a message back to the parent app.

The messaging bit works because the parent is receiving the hard coded part of the value, but the variable also has the value of a property appended to it and it is this value that is not happening.

I can get the property value and display it as part of the component template, but cannot get the value to send back in a message.  If I console.log it, it is an empty string.

Here is my component code:

```
<template>
  <p>{{ label }}</p>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
export default {
  name: "ContentPages",
  emits: ["msgPageTitle"],
  props: {
    label: String
  },
  created() {
    console.log(this.label);
    this.$emit("msgPageTitle", this.label + " Page");
  }
};
</script>

<style>
p {
  color: red;
}
</style>
```

It is the `label` property that works in the template, but not in the $emit (or console.log). What am I missing?

Comment: `label` is a prop of component, so it's depend on what did you send from parent component. Not sure but you can try to print out `this.$props.label` or `this.props.label` to console.

Comment: Sorry, I just saw your edit. I think props are not received in the `created` hook. Not sure about that but may be hooks `mounted`

Comment: Tried mounted - same problem

Comment: Tried `updated` - that is doing the trick - cheers Thanh Dao for pointing me in that direction

Comment: url: https://sfc.vuejs.org/#__DEV__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

Comment: @Graham Great you found a solution, but there is nothing wrong with the component you show. I have put your component in Vue the playground and it is working (See url in my other comment). So it must be in the parent component(s).

Comment: @Gabe - I see you are using a `<Comp>` tag in your app template.  That's not one I'm familiar with - will have a look and see what that is all about

Comment: @Graham that’s just the name I gave to your component.

Comment: Since it is working with `updated()`, I suspect you might be getting the label from an async api in some parent component.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem with your component. It works well.

The only thing, I guess, could possibly be a problem, is the way you have to define `v-on:|@`. If you are writing your Vue templates directly in the DOM, like it is here with the Vue App Template directly in the HTML, then the event binding should not be written in **CamelCase** as your Event name is, but in **kebab-case**.

Like this:

```
@msg-page-title="myHandler"
```

Here is the Vue Doc about [DOM Template Parsing Caveats](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#dom-template-parsing-caveats)

And the working playground:

```js
const { createApp } = Vue;

const MyComponent = {
  name: "ContentPages",
  emits: ["msgPageTitle"],
  props: {
    label: String
  },
  created() {
    console.log("Label: " + this.label);
    this.$emit("msgPageTitle", this.label + " Page");
  },
  template: `<p>{{ label }}</p>`   
}

const App = {
  components: {
    MyComponent
  },
  methods: {
    myHandler(e) {
       console.log("Event: " + e);
    }
  }
}

const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```css
p {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">        
    <my-component label="My Label" @msg-page-title="myHandler">
    </my-component>        
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything is ok, it seems you are missing the event handler in the parent component ?

```
<ComponentChild 
     label="something"
     @msgPageTitle="func($event)"
/>
```

Note: $event is data sent from this.$emit in the child component